# Determine the principal part of the function,poles, singularities and find the residues???

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

c. $1-\cos z\over z^2$ and d. $\frac 1{(z-\pi)^4}$.

c. This is what I have got so far

removable singular point at $z_0=0$ of the function, $f(0)=1/2$, $m=1$ and $b=1/2$

residue =$1/2$ as series =$1/2!-z^4/4!+z^4/6!....$

d. $\frac 1{(z-\pi)^4}$ still confused on this one. 
Would it be an essential singularity =0 for z=pi ???
Series (1/z)^4+4pi/z^5+10pi^2/z^6+....?????

Answer (score 1):

If a singularity is removable then the residue is $0$. This should be obvious from the definition of a residue as the coefficient in front of $\frac 1{z-z_0}$ in the series expansion.

For the second one, your series expansion is wrong. Find the correct one and you will have the answer at once. Hint: it is MUCH easier than what you wrote.

Another hint: if a meromorphic function has an antiderivative in a neighbourhood of a pole, then automatically its residue at that pole is $0$. What makes $1\over z-z_0$ so special is that it doesn't have an antiderivative around $z_0$, unlike any other power (positive or negative) of $z-z_0$.

Comment: Thanks Arnaud. Would it be an essential singularity =0 for z=pi ???

Comment: Series (1/z)^4+4pi/z^5+10pi^2/z^6+....?????

Comment: Still much easier than that. Would you by any chance be able to compute an anti.derivative of $f$? Imagine it was $\frac 1{z^4}$, what would you say?

Comment: -1/3 coefficient?

Comment: Yes, times.......? I edited the answer to help you finish.

Comment: Thanks again :) so its a pole, residue 0, series as I have stated .....

Comment: @Liz Absolutely!